# HTML form data not received by Tornado class

Tags: python, html, websocket, tornado

I'm using WebSockets in the Tornado Framework and can't get the data in a html form to be sent to a tornado class.

This is my code:

```
class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    event = []
    def get(self):
        self.render('main.html')             

    def post(self):
        MainHandler.event = self.get_argument('event')
```

When I try and send event to a WebSocketHandler class. no data is received from the form:

```
class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):

    def open(self):
            print "tailing..."
            db = Connection().blah
            coll = db.blah_tail

            event = MainHandler.event
            print 'Filtered', event
```

'Filtered' just prints an empty list: "Filtered []".

The html form:

```
<form action="/" method="post">
            <input type="text" name="event" />
            <input type="submit" id="open" value="Submit Query" />
        </form>
```

How could you send the form data to the WSHandler class?

Thanks

The js for creating the websocket:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var ws;

        $("#open").click(function(evt){
        evt.preventDefault();

        ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + "localhost" + ":" + "8888" + "/ws");

        ws.onmessage = function(evt) $("#display").append(evt.data + "<br />");

        ws.onclose = function(evt) {alert("Server connection terminated");};
    });
   }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: Does it work if you override the method `on_message(self, message)` instead of `open` inside your `WSHandler`?

Comment: I'm a newbie to Tornado, so how could you override that method.

Comment: You just change `def open(self):` to `def on_message(self, message):`.

Comment: Not an expert in Tornado, but why are you setting a class attribute - `MainHandler.event` - with something that depends on a specific instance - `self.get_...` - in the `MainHandler.post` method?

Comment: If I try to override it then that method is not executed. I use self.get_argument to obtain the form data and then set it as a class attribute so that instance could be used by other classes.

Comment: If you want to share some information, I would suggest using something like a queue, so that you don't risk overwriting the events from other objects that weren't handled yet.

Comment: Thanks problem is I get a TypeError: 'module' object is not callable, when I try and use Queue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like in the example from the Tornado documentation, I'll use a `set` for the WebSocket clients. Improving this is left as an exercise for the reader.

```py
# clients listing on the WebSocket
clients = set()

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        return self.render("index.html")

    def post(self):
        global clients

        event = self.get_argument("event")
        print "got event", event
        if not clients:
            print "No WebSockets, no point in querying the database"
            return
        for coordinate in self.get_coordinates(event):
            for client in clients:
                print "sending coordinate", coordinate, "to client", client
                client.write_message(json.dumps(coordinate,
                                                default=json_util.default))

    def get_coordinates(self, event):
        # replace with a real database query
        for coordinate in ("No", "man's", "land"):
            time.sleep(1)
            yield coordinate

class WSHandler(tornado.websocket.WebSocketHandler):
    def open(self):
        global clients
        print "WebSocket opened..."
        clients.add(self)

    def on_close(self):
        global clients
        print "WebSocket closed..."
        clients.remove(self)
```

The relevant part of the `index.html` template:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            var ws;
            // open WebSocket for getting the results
            ws = new WebSocket("ws://" + location.host + "/ws");
            ws.onmessage = function(evt) {
                $("#display").append(evt.data + "<br>");
            };
            ws.onclose = function(evt) {alert("Server connection terminated");};

            $("#open").click(function(evt) {
                evt.preventDefault();
                $.post("/", $("#eventForm").serialize());
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Event follower</h1>
    <h2>Enter the event you would like to follow</h2>
    <form id="eventForm" action="/" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="event" />
        <input type="submit" id="open" value="Submit Query" />
    </form>
    <h2>Coordinates</h2>
    <div id="display">
    </div>
</body>
```

When the page is loaded, a WebSocket connection is made to the server to the `WSHandler` class and the client is added to the `clients` set. When the page is closed, the WebSocket connection is closed and the server will remove it from the set.

When the **open** submit button is clicked, the form will be submitted asynchronously using AJAX to `MainHandler.post`. The method will find out the coordinates related to that event and send them to the listening clients as they come it. The browser receives each coordinate and it appends it to the **display** `div`.

Answer (score 1):

What is the handler of your function 
MainHandler or WSHandler,

Only One of them call at a single time so your syntax
`event = MainHandler.event`   won't produce any result for you.

1. If your objective is only to submit the form.
   Then on Submit type of event you have to write a post or get function associated with your submit call in your JS, That will work with normal tornado.web.RequestHandler on server side.

Ref. [tornado web socket chat example](https://github.com/facebook/tornado/blob/master/demos/websocket)

I have updated the chat example :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (!window.console) window.console = {};
    if (!window.console.log) window.console.log = function() {};
    $("#messageform").live("submit", function() {
            newMessage($(this));
            return false;
     });
     $("#message").select();
    }
});

function newMessage(form) {
        var message = form.formToDict();
        var disabled = form.find("input[type=submit]");
        disabled.disable();
        $.postJSON("URL", message, function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        });
    }

    function getCookie(name) {
        var r = document.cookie.match("\\b" + name + "=([^;]*)\\b");
        return r ? r[1] : undefined;
    }

    jQuery.postJSON = function(url, args, callback) {
        args._xsrf = getCookie("_xsrf");
        $.ajax({url: url, data: $.param(args), dataType: "text", type: "POST",
                success: function(response) {
            if (callback) callback(eval("(" + response + ")"));
        }, error: function(response) {
            console.log("ERROR:", response)
        }});
    };
```

When you will call `$("#message").submit()` you will receive form data in you "URL" function

**If you want's to use WSHandler then**

**Ref. [example link](http://mbed.org/cookbook/Websockets?action=view&revision=3476) will help you.**

See if this helps.

Comment: Thanks, still not sure how that will work. When I've passed form data previously to a tornado class all I had to do was eg. <form action ="/" method = "post"> In the tornado class I just used the get_argument method and that has worked.

Comment: It's the MainHandler I want to use to get the form data, this is the one I'm using for the form function. Once it is received server side then I want the data to be used by WSHandler. Thanks for the example link, I used that to send data real-time data to the client.

Comment: Are you creating websocket, how you are doing it, paste your js code in you question. OR tell me if you won't write one. then my friend you are missing the concept of websocket check out the example link i posted

Comment: I know that its MainHandler that's whay i am saying how your think you WSHandler called.

Comment: updated original post with js - WSHandler called here: (r'/ws', WSHandler)

Comment: You know this statement event = MainHandler.event won't give you any value even its wrong writing this, becoz your URL is not MainHandler its WSHandler. you will receive you data on 
`def on_message(self, event):
    print 'events : %s' % event`
i assume you have added an handler for WSHandler in your application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19378/discussion-between-rahul-gautam-and-user94628)